# Searching Parse collected by File field's name

Tags: parse-platform

I have object `Media` with field `file` in front of S3 backend. I want to search collection by the filename of the `file` field. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cloud Code:

```
var filename = "my-image.png";

var query = new Parse.Query("Media")
    .equals("file", filename);

query.find().then(function (results) {
    // Do something
});
```